# correct syntax for sql query and a WHERE EXISTS alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

I want to write the following query in order to return all the jobs from the jobs table where the profession and subprofession pair equal one of the profession and subprofession pairs for a certain user (one of 4 pairs). if the user has a pair where the subprofession=0, that means take all the subprofessions for the respective profession:

something like this:

```
select * from jobs j
where 
      (j.profession, j.subprofession) in 

      (select (u.profession1, u.subprofession1) from users u where userid=@userid),
       select (u.profession2, u.subprofession2) from users u where userid=@userid),
       select (u.profession3, u.subprofession3) from users u where userid=@userid),
       select (u.profession4, u.subprofession4) from users u where userid=@userid)
and
j.profession in (select u.profession1, u.profession2, u.profession3, u.profession4 from users u where userid=@userid) and (u.subprofession1 = 0 or u.subprofession2 = 0 or u.subprofession3 = 0 or u.subprofession4 = 0))
```

I know this query is syntactically wrong and does not do what it is supposed to, so what is the way to acheive the above purpose using either IN clause or WHERE EXISTS?

```
jobs: profession, subprofession 
1      (100,        200)
2      (100,        300)
3      (100,        400)
4      (100,        500)
5      (200,        300)
6      (400,        500)
7      (400,        100)
8      (400,        600)
9      (200,        200)
10     (600,        700)
11     (100,        100)
12     (500,        300)
13     (200,        200)

users: (prof1, subprof1, prof2, subprof2, prof3, subprof3, prof4, subprof4)
1       (100,   100,      757,   646,      100,   0,        500,   400)
2       (100,   2,        565,   76,       567,   534,      433,   565)
3       (200,   454,      553,   345,      354,   435,      334,   877)
4       (500,   300,      456,   565,      354,   435,      545,   435)
5       (400,   453,      434,   453,      423,   234,      324,   4435)
6       (100,   400,      435,   543,      465,   654,      454,   543)
7       (435,   435,      600,   700,      100,   0,        500,   400)
8       (100,   100,      553,   345,      100,   0,        500,   400)
```

the requested query would return from the jobs table rows:
1,2,3,4,11

these are the rows where the values of profession and subprofession (as a pair) appear in one of the users prof and subprof pairs. also, because for user 1 there is an entry (prof3=100 and subprof3=0), the query should return all of the orders where the proession is 100 (for all the subprofessions).

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: it would also be useful to have some example tables and expected results for the query

Comment: This is not clear: `if the user has a pair where the subprofession=0, that means take all the subprofessions for the respective profession`

Comment: Do you have any influence on the database design? You could move the relation between user and profession/subprofession to relation tables (user-profession, user-subprofession, profession-subprofession).

@Tim If the user did not specify a subprofession (think specialization), then get all jobs for the profession. Otherwise just those that match the subprofession, I guess.

Comment: OK: Is this understanding correct: If we have (100,100) in pair1 and (100,0) in pair3, we should not eliminate jobs in profession 100 that require subprofession 100, because the 0 in pair3 is a "wildcard" meaning "any job in the specfied profession"; pair3 overrides pair1 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Jobs
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Users
            WHERE   Users.UserID = @UserID
            AND (   (Users.Profession1 = Jobs.Profession AND Users.SubProfession1 IN (Jobs.SubProfession, 0))
                OR  (Users.Profession2 = Jobs.Profession AND Users.SubProfession2 IN (Jobs.SubProfession, 0))
                OR  (Users.Profession3 = Jobs.Profession AND Users.SubProfession3 IN (Jobs.SubProfession, 0))
                OR  (Users.Profession4 = Jobs.Profession AND Users.SubProfession4 IN (Jobs.SubProfession, 0))
                )
        );
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3686/11)**

**EDIT**

Since it is SQL-Server, You could use `CROSS APPLY..VALUES` to unpivot the data, this way you can inner join and establish whether the job is match because subprofession is 0, or whether there is an exact subprofession match:

```
WITH UserProf AS
(   SELECT  DISTINCT
            Users.UserID,
            p.Profession,
            p.SubProfession
    FROM    Users
            CROSS APPLY
            (VALUES
                (Profession1, SubProfession1),
                (Profession2, SubProfession2),
                (Profession3, SubProfession3),
                (Profession4, SubProfession4)
            ) p (Profession, SubProfession)
    WHERE   Users.UserID = @UserID
)
SELECT  Jobs.*, 
        MatchType = CASE WHEN MIN(UserProf.SubProfession) = 0 THEN 'All Subprofession' ELSE 'Exact subprofession' END
FROM    Jobs
        INNER JOIN UserProf
            ON UserProf.Profession = Jobs.Profession
            AND UserProf.SubProfession IN (0, Jobs.SubProfession)
GROUP BY Jobs.JobID, Jobs.Profession, Jobs.SubProfession;
```

**[Example on SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3686/12)**

Comment: will the first query work in ms access enviroment also despite the use of the exists keyword ?

Comment: Yes, Access supports `EXISTS` so the first query will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would much rather look at a query written two years ago that is self-documenting than at one where I have to puzzle out what it's doing. Of course, something that's a puzzler for me might be someone else's easy-as-pie.

Given the wildcard power of zero in the subprofession slot, meaning "match on profession, don't worry about the subprofession", I would approach the query as the union of two sets.

Set 1 is the set of all jobs matching a user's professions where subprofession =0.
Set 2 is the set of all jobs matching a user's profession/subprofession dyad.

So the first step would be to get, for each user, the list of distinct professions where the subprofession doesn't matter. This gets inner-joined to jobs on profession.

The second step would be to get, for each user, the list of distinct dyads, i.e. where the subprofession does matter.  This gets inner joined to jobs on profession and subprofession.

If you wanted, each join could append a column indicating MatchLevel, i.e. ProfessionOnly in the first set and Both in the second set, but then you could see the same job listed twice, once for general match and once for the specific match.